# Multiplayer game with Cocos2d-Javascript and Node.js

Tags: multiplayer, javascript, cocos2d, websocket, node.js

It is possible to make a multiplayer browser based game using cocos2d-javascript + node.js? If so, is there any tutorial about that?

Comment: What kind of game? Multiplayer can be anything from scrabble to a first person shooter... be more specific.

Comment: I think you didin't understand the question. What I want to know is if it's possible to use these two technologies (cocos2d-javascript - cocos2d-javascript.org - and node.js) together.

Comment: It means any kind of game I can make with cocos2d-javascript, so a first person shooter isn't included...

Comment: cocos2d together with node.js should work perfectly fine IMO. Node.js is server-side and doesn't impose much limitations when it comes to the client-side library or language.

Comment: Yeah, I know that but I don't realize how to do that. Do you know any tutorial or blog post about that? It could be just a simple game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend you check into http://nodejs.org/ and https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/ for information on what you can do with node.js.

cocos2d-javascript has a tutorials section on their website: http://cocos2d-javascript.org/tutorials/ which I recommend you start with.

Without significantly more detail, there isn't much more I can recommend you look at.